# Programmatically Add/Remove User to Audience

Tags: 2010, user, audience-targeting, audiences

I've been searching everywhere for information on how to programmatically add a user to an Audience. Is this at all possible? We'd like to set up Audiences as a kind of "Subscription" base where our users can receive content according to what Audiences they are subscribed to.

I've literally found nothing through the API or Google, and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge you do not add User to an Audience, but rather build rules that would include the respective user to an audience.

Creating rule based Audiences is available here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms498178

Then you could check is user is part of an Audience in a particular Web, see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms500775

Comment: Thanks, that's what we expected too. So it looks like we can't get our users to be able to subscribe to an Audience. However, we found out that we can do Target Audience filtering on groups, so I think we'll go that route. Hopefully you can add a user to a group programmatically!

Comment: Yes indeed, audiences could include groups too, and yes it is very simple to add users to groups, quick g-search: http://geekswithblogs.net/madhawa/archive/2008/11/18/127171.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hope these links help

http://blog.kappasolutions.ca/blog/post/2010/09/30/Create-SharePoint-2010-Audiences-Using-PowerShell.aspx

[User profile Audience Using Power shell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34142/user-profile-audience-using-power-shell)