# Powershell and accessing Audiences

Tags: 2010, powershell, audiences

I'm trying to build a fully functioning powershell script that will merge user accounts, loop through all the site collections and delete the 2 user accounts, then execute audience compilation. I've got parts 1 and 2 working after a bit of work, but I'm hung up on hooking into audiences. I've seen [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34142/user-profile-audience-using-power-shell) by Per, and it always bombs out on line 3 with:

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object." At line:3 char:18
>   + $upm = New-Object <<<<  Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context); 
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

If I do a `$context`, it gives me a GUID of all zeroes. I'm developing this on my local windows 7 machine, full admin access to everything.

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://localhost" 
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site; 
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context); 
$audmgr = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience.AudienceManager($context)
$aud = $audmgr.GetAudience("Irvine")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bleh, I wasn't listed in the permissions of the service application even though I was listed as an administrator.

[image]

Image and fix courtesy of [get-spscripts](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/07/modify-single-value-user-profile.html)

Answer (score 0):

Someone over on the MSDN forums had the same issue.  They fixed it by changing the way the context was instantiated.  Basically do this:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server")
$context = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($mysite)
$upm =  New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
```

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7acf5c34-798b-4cee-a219-96d1ba4832c9/create-user-profile-manager-class-instance-using-powershell?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious